# sequence of linearly independent vectors

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Lets say that we have I linerly independent vectors $\{v_1,v_2,...,v_I\}$.

And lets say that we have a sequence of vectors $\{x^k\}^k$, where $x^k=\Sigma_Ic_i^kv_i$.

Lets say that the sequence of these vectors($\{x^k\}^k$) go to zero, must then for each i, $\{c_i^k\}^k$, go to zero?

It seems logical, since the sequence is a linear combination of linerly indpendent vectors, and a sum of linearly indpendent vectors is zero only if each constant infront of each vector is zero. The problem here is that as we go to zero we get so close to zero as we want, but we may never get exactly zero, so I am struggling with the technical aspect of proving this.

Can you please help?

Basically we have from linear algebra that a linear combination of linearly independent vectors are 0 if and only each each constant infront of each vector is zero. I need that if we have a linear combination of linearly independent vectors this is "small" if and only if constant is "small", is this true?

Answer (score 0):

Let $\varepsilon>0$. Since the sequence $(x^k)_k$ goes to $0$, we know that there is $K>0$ such that for all $k>K$ it holds true that $\|x^k\|<\varepsilon$. Hence by [question here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/694228/inequality-for-norm-of-linear-combination-of-linearly-independent-vectors), we know that there exist a positive constant $a$ such that

$$a|c_j^k| \leq \|x^k\|<\varepsilon$$

for $j \in \{1,\ldots, I\}$ and $k>K$. This means that the sequences $(c_j^k)_j$ converge to $0$.